# Are North aurora and South aurora produced by positive and negative particles respectively?

Tags: astrophysics, earth, atmospheric-science, geophysics, solar-wind

Are North aurora and South aurora produced by positive and negative particles respectively?

Comment: "_Polarity charges_", like, positive ions vs. negative ions?

Comment: Yeah! This is what I mean.

Comment: I will shift to a  answer when this is taken off hold. It is not the electron flux from the solar wind itself that cuases most of the aurora, but the ionised N2 in columns above the poles acting as a 'wall', and resultant interactions making photons https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora#Auroras_and_the_atmosphere The auroras are different, seasonally & daily.

Comment: But in North and South pole, the ionised N2 are caused by the impact of different polarity ions of solar wind, since the geomagnetic field have the only direction, right?

Comment: Ions of either charge + or -  have an equal tendency to follow (spiral around)  magnetic field lines in either direction, towards a north or a south pole

Comment: As far as I know, solar wind particle move with Larmor gyration in geomagnetic field, thus, they move along the field lind, and the direction is random?

Answer (score 4):

No, they're not separated in this way.

Recall that a moving charge in a uniform magnetic field will experience a force perpendicular to the field.  This causes it to "circle" around the magnetic field lines.  The only direction it can easily travel long distances is parallel to the the field lines (in either direction).

So the difference between charges isn't their large-scale motion (along the field lines), but the short-scale motion (the direction of their helix).

For the earth, the magnetic field intersects the atmosphere most strongly near the poles, so that is where charged particles tend to be funneled.  Both species are driven there.

The particular location it will be driven to depends on what part of the field it interacts with.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the the direction of the charged particles are depended on their initial velocity when they  enter atmosphere?

Comment: The spin direction depends on the pole and the charge of the particle.  The travel direction depends on what field line they are following to the surface.

Comment: I am still confused to it. For the travel direction，the geomagnetic field line start from north magnetic poles to the south, and particles following the line, moving to North or South, or by random?  What determine their direction?

Comment: There's no force on a charge when it travels parallel to the field lines.  So there's no preference to direction.  Based on how it intersects the field, it might move either way.